# SugarCRM api (Rest Webservice call) for Database Schema

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

I am looking SugarCRM API (Rest Webservice call) for Database Schema.

Where can I get details of all the tables, entities, Column names, relationship available in SugarCRM?

I want to get Metadata. I have API's for CRUD operations but I want to find schema API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of available API calls for SugarCRM 7.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.5/API/Web_Services/Examples/v10/index.html.

Here is a link for the database scheme.

http://apidocs.sugarcrm.com/schema/7.6.1.0/ent/

As far as I know there isn't a schema API. To get all fields (core and custom) for a module you'd have to query 1 record to retrieve the fields list.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one API for retrieving schema.

Using this URL " {site url}/rest/v10/metadata"

we can get schema for all the tables available in SugarCRM in one shot.